# How to extract single and double sentence based on starting keyword using regex

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
keyword1 = ['Admit:']
Keyword2 = ['Discharge:']

Sentence = "Admit: 15/06/2019 was been in HR hospital. This is usual precaution for accidents. Discharge: 18/06/2019 discharged from A/C room. This is from BRK Hospital.
```

Tried: (Incorrect code)

```
import re
a = "Admit: 15/06/2019 was been in HR hospital. This is usual precaution for accidents. Discharge: 18/06/2019 discharged from A/C room. This is from BRK Hospital."
x = re.findall("^Admit: [.]$", a)
print(x)
```

Required solution:

```
Admit: 15/06/2019 was been in HR hospital.
Discharge: 18/06/2019 discharged from A/C room. This is from BRK Hospital.
```

Is there any solution that for Admit: keyword only need to take upto first fullstop and for Discharge: keyword need to take upto two fullstop using regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are looking for the first full stop after Admit:, you can use this:

```
x = re.findall("^Admit:[^.]*.", a)
```

For the second part, you can just allow it to find till the end:

```
x = re.findall("Discharge:.*", a)
```

Comment: But for "Discharge: 18/06/2019 discharged from A/C room. This is from BRK Hospital." Thats not the end of the sentence but there may other lines after that. How to find exact two full stops?

Comment: You could just repeat the Admit aspect twice. For more advanced stuff check out https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

Comment: a = "Admit: 15/06/2019 was been in HR hospital. This is usual precaution for accidents. Discharge: 18/06/2019 discharged from A/C room. This is from BRK Hospital."y = re.findall("^Discharge:[^.]*.", a)print(y).....Unable to get solution "Discharge: 18/06/2019 discharged from A/C room."

Comment: Since Discharge keyword is not in first index

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the approach:

```
import re
Sentence = "Admit: 15/06/2019 was been in HR hospital. This is usual precaution for accidents. Discharge: 18/06/2019 discharged from A/C room. This is from BRK Hospital."

admit = re.search(r'(^Admit:.*?)\..*(Discharge:.*)', Sentence)
print (admit.group(1))
# Extract data until second full stop
print ('.'.join(admit.group(2).split('.')[:2]))
```

Output:

```
Admit: 15/06/2019 was been in HR hospital
Discharge: 18/06/2019 discharged from A/C room. This is from BRK Hospital
```